# Can I browse source/commits on dotcloud?

Tags: django, version-control, repository, dotcloud

I've got Django app deployed on Dotcloud. Is there any way to browse my commits/source and use Dotcloud also as version-control system? Or I still need to store my code somewhere else.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to store your code somewhere else.

dotCloud uses git and mercurial as a transport mechanism but you can't rely on it for long term storage or retrieval. It is best to store it on your own servers or someplace like github, bitbucket, etc.

If you need more info about dotClouds git and mercurial push features check out this page.

http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/git-hg/

Answer (score 2):

[dotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) isn't intended to be a version control system, so its recommended that you use a tool like [hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/) or [git](http://git-scm.com/) while developing your code.  There are free and paid version control hosting options at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and [Github](https://github.com/) for both of these tools.

That said, using the [dotCloud command line tool](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/migration/) (CLI), you can see your last few deployment versions and can re-deploy them.  You could then ssh into the code container and view the code deployed, however you don't have tools, like diff, to compare changes between deployed versions (which you'll get with a true vcs).

Check the Revision:

```
$ dotcloud revisions -A <application>
==> Revisions for application <application>:
  rsync-1361893583994
  rsync-1361894923509
  rsync-1361896157246
  rsync-1361896963821
* rsync-1361897866164
```

Deploy a previous version:

```
dotcloud deploy -A <application> rsync-1361893583994
```

Deploy the latest (most recently pushed):

```
dotcloud deploy -A <application> latest
```

Ssh into the container to see what's deployed:

```
dotcloud run -A <application> <service name>
```